# Express error handler (and middleware) called constantly

Tags: node.js, express

```
app.use('/', (err, req, res, next) => {
  debugger;
  if (!err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
    res.redirect(redirectUrl);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

I'm using error handler in Express and running the Chrome Node debugger. Every 2 seconds or so, it catches on the `debugger`. Looks like it is a socket message (I'm not using sockets).

What is going on here? From the browser, there is only one request. But every two second this error handler is running.

**Simplifying it even more..**

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.url);
  next();}
);
```

results in a ...

```
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
```

Comment: results is...
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json

Comment: updated my question